# mysql get count and average

Tags: mysql

I have a table of questionnaire responses with a question ID, and a value that a user submitted.

I would like to get the counts of responses, and also the average for the whole question ID, so for example for question ID 1, there was a count of 3 for option 1, and acount of 2 for option 2, but the OVERALL average would be 7(sum of all optons) divided by 5(total submissions).

I can't see how to do this with my group by, which does a total of resposnses grouped by questions ID and also option number.

Any pointers would be gratefully received!

Sample data would look like

```
questionID  ResponseValue
1           5
1           5
1           6
2           7
2           7
2           7
2           3
```

My expected output would be

```
questionID responseValue countOfResponses questionAverage
1          5             2                5.3333
1          6             1                5.3333
2          3             1                6
2          7             3                6
```

Comment: can you add atleast sample records

Comment: SHOW a column representation of your EXPECTED OUTPUT TOO.  Otherwise, its just a simple select AVG( ResponseValue ) from YourTable... 1 record = 5.333.  How do you expect to show the correlation of the 5 answered twice, and 6 answered once otherwise... you need a group by for that.

Comment: I have updated the question to show required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like...
On a per-option with overall total, I would pre-query the per question sum(value of responses), then group just on the question so you have that for all entries... then query again, but on a per question/option...  So, in this case, you are getting the percentage of the total a given response represents, not an "average"... To ensure you get decimal precision, I've added * 1.0000 so it goes to a decimal forced result column and not just integer.

```
select
      YT.QuestionID,
      YT.responseValue,
      count(*) as TotalOptResponses,
      TotalByQ.TotalQAverage
   from
      YourTable  YT
         JOIN ( select QuestionID,
                       avg(ResponseValue * 1.0000 ) as TotalQAverage
                   from
                      YourTable
                   group by
                      QuestionID ) TotalByQ
            ON YT.QuestionID = TotalByQ.QuestionID
   group by
      YT.QuestionID,
      YT.ResponseValue
```

Comment: Not quite, as I need to know the count per option

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't seem to be getting the results I expected. I have edited the original question to give a sample of some data and an explanation of the results I need to see.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this has now been implemented successfully. I guess there is no way to do this without the subselect because it needs to group by different things.